# compare the triplets C# hackerrank improving my solution

Tags: c#

I've been trying to solve this hackerrank practice question ([Compare the Triplets](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/compare-the-triplets)) and I have no idea where I'm wrong.  My output is correct but it does not pass all of hackerrank's test cases.  Any advice?

Problem:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Linq;
    class Solution {

static void Main(String[] args) {
    string[] tokens_a0 = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
    int a0 = Convert.ToInt32(tokens_a0[0]);
    int a1 = Convert.ToInt32(tokens_a0[1]);
    int a2 = Convert.ToInt32(tokens_a0[2]);
    string[] tokens_b0 = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
    int b0 = Convert.ToInt32(tokens_b0[0]);
    int b1 = Convert.ToInt32(tokens_b0[1]);
    int b2 = Convert.ToInt32(tokens_b0[2]);
    // Write Your Code Here
    int aliceScore = 0;
    int bobScore = 0;


    if(a0 > b0 || a1 > b1 || a2 > b2)
    {
       aliceScore++;    
    }
    if(b0 > a0 || b1 > a1 || b2 > a2)
    {
        bobScore++;
    }
    if(a0 == b0 || a1 == b1 || a2 == b2)
    {
        aliceScore += 0;
        bobScore += 0;
    }

    Console.WriteLine(aliceScore +" " + bobScore);

}
```

}

Comment: I think your 3rd if statement has no purpose.

Comment: In your version either player can have only 0 or 1 point. That's obviously wrong

Comment: Let your code  have constraints provided in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I see the problem, you need to compare each data point and calculate the score for each one. So, compare data point 0, then data point 1 then data point 2.

Pseudo code is below, have not tested:

```
    if(a0 > b0)
    {
       aliceScore++;    
    }
    else if(b0 > a0)
    {
        bobScore++;
    }


    if(a1 > b1)
    {
        aliceScore++;
    }
    else if(b1 > a1)
    {
        bobScore++;
    }

    if(a2 > b2)
    {
        aliceScore++;
    }
    else if(b2 > a2)
    {
        bobScore++;
    }
```

Comment: Ty GER.  I now realize that I wasn't attacking this problem at each comparison point.  Is there a technical term that describes my approach?  May I also ask what was your thought process as you looked at the problem?

Comment: For this small problem, I broke it down on paper (in my head) and solved it manually without writing any code. Thats harder to do with bigger puzzles and real world problems. I am not sure if your original approach has a term.

Answer (score 0):

GER provides the steps to the logic behind solving the problem.  Your solution should ideally be able to cater for any input provided in the arrays for either Alice or Bob.  Let's say we have two Lists of type int.

```
var a = new List<int> {10, 11, 12, 14, 45 };
var b = new List<int> {8, 15, 10, 12, 55 };
```

Say list "a" represents score tally for Alice and list "b" for Bob.  The solution requires comparison of entries at the same index positions from either list i.e. from left to right number 10 from list "a" is at index 0 and number 8 from list "b" is at index 0 as well.  The function that processes the task of comparing will accept both lists as input, and then return a list containing 2 entries.  The function's return will be a score for Alice and a Score for Bob.  See example solution below

```
void Main()
{
    var a = new List<int> { 10, 11, 12, 14, 45 };
    var b = new List<int> { 8, 15, 10, 12, 55 };

    var result = CompareScores(a, b);

    //Expected result is : 
    // Alice: 3
    // Bob: 2

    Console.WriteLine($"Alice score: {result.ElementAt(0)} Bob score: {result.ElementAt(1)}");
}

public List<int> CompareScores(List<int> alice, List<int> bob)
{
    var ScoreAlice = 0;
    var ScoreBob = 0;
    var i = 0;
    alice.ForEach(scoreAlice => {
        if(scoreAlice > bob.ElementAt(i))
        {
            ScoreAlice ++;
        }
        if(scoreAlice < bob.ElementAt(i))
        {
            ScoreBob ++;
        }
        i++;
    });
    return new List<int> {ScoreAlice, ScoreBob };
}
```

In my solution notice I have used Linq to iterate over List representing Alice and for each element I compare against Bob's list identifying the element using the value of "i".

Answer (score -1):

Working Solution:

```
 public static List<int> compareTriplets(List<int> a, List<int> b)
 {    
     int alice = 0;
     int bob = 0;
        
     for(int j =0 ; j < a.Count; j++){
       if (a[j] > b[j]) {
            alice +=1;                
       }else if(b[j] > a[j]){
            bob +=1;                
       }else{
            continue;
            }
        }
        
     return new List<int> {alice, bob};    
  }
```

Comment: Code only answers are **not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. Answers are better with an explanation. The solution may be obvious to you. To others it may not. Please explain what it does, and how it's different from existing answers. Otherwise this answer may be flagged as [Low Quality](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality). Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

I think this is not a correct way to solve this problem. You should follow these
steps given below.

```
        int[] Alice = { a0, a1, a2 };
        int[] Bob = { b0, b1, b2 };
        int alice = 0;
        int bob = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < Alice.Length; i++)
        {
            if (Alice[i] > Bob[i])
            {
                alice++;
            }
            if (Alice[i] < Bob[i])
            {
                bob++;
            }
        }
        int[] result = { alice, bob };
        return result;
```

Answer (score -3):

```
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Text;
using System;

class Solution {

    // Complete the compareTriplets function below.
    static List<int> compareTriplets(List<int> a, List<int> b) {
        int alice=0,bob=0;
        for(int i=0;i<a.Count;i++)
        {
            if(a.ElementAt(i)>b.ElementAt(i))
            {
                alice=alice+1;
            }
            else if(a.ElementAt(i)<b.ElementAt(i))
            {
                bob=bob+1;
            }
        }
        return new List<int> {alice,bob};

    }

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(@System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("OUTPUT_PATH"), true);

        List<int> a = Console.ReadLine().TrimEnd().Split(' ').ToList().Select(aTemp => Convert.ToInt32(aTemp)).ToList();

        List<int> b = Console.ReadLine().TrimEnd().Split(' ').ToList().Select(bTemp => Convert.ToInt32(bTemp)).ToList();

        List<int> result = compareTriplets(a, b);

        textWriter.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", result));

        textWriter.Flush();
        textWriter.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

class Solution {

```
// Complete the compareTriplets function below.
static List<int> compareTriplets(List<int> a, List<int> b) {
    int A = 0;
    int B = 0;
    
    for(int i=0; i < a.Count; i++){
        if(a[i] > b[i]){
            A++;
        
        }else if(a[i] < b[i]){
            B++;
        }
    }
    return new List<int> {A,B};        
}

static void Main(string[] args) {
    TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(@System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("OUTPUT_PATH"), true);

    List<int> a = Console.ReadLine().TrimEnd().Split(' ').ToList().Select(aTemp => Convert.ToInt32(aTemp)).ToList();

    List<int> b = Console.ReadLine().TrimEnd().Split(' ').ToList().Select(bTemp => Convert.ToInt32(bTemp)).ToList();

    List<int> result = compareTriplets(a, b);

    textWriter.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", result));

    textWriter.Flush();
    textWriter.Close();
}
```

}

Answer (score -3):

I think this will work fine.

```
        List<int> res = new() { 0, 0 };

        for (int i = 0; i < a.Count; i++)
        {
            if (a[i] > b[i]) res[0]++;
            else if (a[i] < b[i]) res[1]++;
        }
```

Answer (score -3):

```
vector<int> compareTriplets(vector<int> a, vector<int> b)
{
    int testsubjects=0;
    int s=0;
    int d=0;
    for(int i=0;i<testsubjects;i++)
    {
        s+= a[i]>b[i] ? 1:0;
        d+=a[i]<b[i] ? 1:0;
    }
    vector<int> vect = vector<int> {s,d};
    return vect;
}
```

Comment: Why? What's the benefit of this one over the eight existing answers? Do you use new syntax that wasn't available when the accepted answer was written four years ago? Are there problems with the existing seven answers? Please help readers understand why your approach adds to the conversation.

Answer (score -3):

u can try with this:

```
int alice = 0; 
int bob = 0; 
int totalTest = 3; 
List<int> result = new List<int>(); 

for(var i=0; i<totalTest; i++)
{
    if(a[i] > b[i]){
        alice++; 
    }else if(a[i] < b[i]){
         bob++; 
    }
}
        
result.Add(alice); 
result.Add(bob); 
return result;
```

Comment: A quality answer would include an explanation why (you think) / how this answers the question. Can you elaborate on that?

Answer (score -3):

```
    var res = new List<int>{0,0};
    var count = a.Count > b.Count ? a :b;
    for(int i =0;i<count.Count;i++){
        if(a[i]>b[i]){
            res[0]+=1;
        }
        else if(b[i]>a[i]){
            res[1]+=1;
        }
        else{
            
        }
    }
    
    return res;
}
```

Comment: How is this an improvement? This would benefit from a bit of explanation. It also doesn't have the same number of open brackets as close brackets